# What is the way to add all the entity classes in one go in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate, following is the code I have written:

```js
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                     .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                     .addAnnotatedClass(AcademicInfo.class)
                     .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                     .buildSessionFactory();
  
  Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
  
  try {
  
  session.beginTransaction();
  
  Student theStudent1 = new Student("Ginny","Wisley","wisleywadi");
  AcademicInfo stuAcademics = new AcademicInfo("Petronous Charm", 2007);
    
  theStudent1.setAcademicDetails(stuAcademics); 
  stuAcademics.setStudentInfo(theStudent1);
  
  System.out.println(theStudent1);

  session.save(theStudent1);
  session.save(stuAcademics);
  
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  
  System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
  
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
   factory.close();
  }
   
  
 }
```

Code works fine, but is there any other way to use hibernate ? 
Someway, where i do not want to mention the addAnnotattedClass for each and every entity(class) and i will get the object of entire database so that i can work on any entity whenever I want.

Comment: Do you understand that the SessionFactory is supposed to be created once and only once, and that all the code should be sing the same, once-built session factory? So, in a real-life application, you would write the first statement only once, and reuse the built factory everywhere?

Comment: Do you have to use Hibernate directly or could you use JPA or also a framework like Spring? What's the purpose of your app?

Comment: @JBNizet - how to use same session factory in all my java classes ? SimonMartinelli - If i use JPA, do i need to use hibernate as well ?

Comment: By making it a singleton that you can access, (or preferred: inject) everywhere you need it. JPA is a standard API, and Hibernate is one of the implementations of this API.

Comment: @JBNizet - what is mostly used in the industry ? with legacy projects?

Comment: AFAIK, Hibernate is the most used implementation of JPA. And most projects use it using the standard JPA API rather than the proprietary Hibernate API.